# Have an ASP.NET endpoint accept a request with a JSON object of unknown type in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I would like to accept an object of a known type where one of the properties is simply a Record<string, any>.  Currently the only way I can get this to work is to force my client to JSON.stringify the property and then I can deserialize it just fine. The issue is that that's not necessary with any other framework I've ever used, so I'd like to allow the client to just pass JSON.

Here is what I'd like to pass, pretending we have events that we POST about specific objects in a system:

```
{
    "eventType" : "created",
    "objectId" : "cb01e673-3835-44a8-a803-7cbfd437f0e2",
    "eventDetails" : 
    {
        "anyKey" : "someValue",
        "someArray" : ["no problem!", "no reason this should not work!"],
        "someNestedObject" : 
        {
            "anyNestedKey" : "should never be an issue"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my request object:

```
public class ObjectEvent
{  
    public string? ObjectId { get; set; }

    public string? EventType { get; set; }
    public dynamic? EventDetails { get; set; } 
}
```

Problem is, when I get EventDetails it looks like this:

```
    Request ValueKind = Object : "{         "whatever": "go for it"     }"
```

This means it's now a JsonElement, but that's not true.  It was just a Json object passed from the client.  I can SEE the object there but I cannot seem to get it into a dynamic.

Again, if I force everyone to serialize the "EventDetails" property as a string before POSTing, I can switch "dynamic? EventDetails" to "string? EventDetails" and use Newtonsoft.Deserialize and it works fine, but that's not really acceptable when people are using curl and postman to access this or writing jest tests.  They should be able to pass an object and .NET should accept it, which it *kind of* is but not in a way that I can use.

Any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Would you need to process `EventDetails` in your code later? What kind of processing are you doing?

Comment: Yes.  Essentially events come in on the wire and can be an ever-expanding number of EventTypes.  The EventDetails shape is truly "any"; that is differs based on several things but mostly based on the EventType.  The business logic after I get it into a Dynamic or Expando picks it apart and makes decisions/other calls based on the contents, then stores a log object with the Details serialized back to JSON.

This all works if I send in a string and just Deserialize the string to a dynamic, but that's clunky for manual integrators.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'd be questioning the design of an API where "anything goes" is a good idea. Usually there are some limitations that can/should be in place (e.g. level of nesting).

Other point: using `dynamic` is in no way different than using `object` - except the point at which any errors are thrown compile time for `object` vs runtime for `dynamic`. And even if dynamic would be giving some benefits, you have no way of knowing at design time what will be inside (if you did, you could use that knowledge to shape the class definition instead of using `dynamic/object`).

Anyway as to a proposed solution: check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/handle-overflow?pivots=dotnet-8-0) for `System.Text.Json` for handling case of overflow JSON - i.e. anything that is not explicitly defined. (If you are using `Newtonsoft.Json` then either migrate (based on which version of .net are you using) or try finding the equivalent way for that library.

In the end you will need to work with the `JsonElement` class anyway. As you write yourself:

> **This means it's now a JsonElement**, *but that's not true*. It was just a Json object passed from the client. I can SEE the object there but *I cannot seem to get it into a dynamic*.

The bold text is true, the text in *italics* is not: it is `JsonElement` and you have it in the `dynamic` and code like this will work just fine:

```
var jsonDetails = (JsonElement)EventDetails;
```

or just change the class definition:

```
public JsonElement? EventDetails { get; set; }
```

Comment: It's not so much that it's anything goes, it's just a fairly common flexible messaging pattern between microservices. I want the object that was sent from the client to be in the dynamic.  How do I get the contents of that Json element into a dynamic type?  I think that's the missing link for me.   When I pass on a string I just deserialize it to dynamic and it's easy peasy.  Now that it's in this Json element, I need to convert it to a dynamic or expando.

Comment: what do you want to do with the data in the dynamic/expando after the conversion?

Comment: Here's what happens when I send it in as a string:

1. I validate the property as valid json
2. I deserialize it to dynamic.
3. Some business logic makes some decisions based on the EventType and also the contents of of the details.  It knows what shape the Details are based on the type etc.   
4.  It then gathers some supporting data and stores a history object about processing the event.   When it does this it serializes the Details back to JSON and stores it.
5.  It returns an echo of what was stored in the DB (OUTPUT INSERTED). It responds with an object not a json string.

Comment: as you seem to have found your answer I won't go into much detail, but my guess would be that you'd be fine with a `JsonElement` property; or, for a bit more refined solution: the business logic could provide derived classes that would map the incoming json exactly to the needed form without the need of an expando/dynamic; e.g. with help of some form of factory pattern

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, much simpler than it might appear!

Given that I have a RequestModel and then a Model that I'm trying to marshal the data to for business logic:

```
public class EventCreateRequest
{ 
    public string? EventType { get; set; }
    public object? EventDetails { get; set; } 
}

public class EventCreateModel
{ 
    public EventTypes EventType { get; set; }
    public ExpandoObject? EventDetails { get; set; } 
}
```

Then the adapter looks like this:

```
public EventCreateModel convertFromCreateRequestToCreateModel(EventCreateRequest request)
{ 
    EventCreateModel model = new EventCreateModel()
    {
        EventType = request.EventType != null ? Enum.Parse<EventTypes>(request.EventType) : null;
 
        EventDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(request.EventDetails.ToString(), new ExpandoObjectConverter());
    } 
    return model;
}
```

Comment: Probably would lead to god object issue for the class handling events. If the project is still in early stage, I'd recommend to specify what EventDetails could be, maybe some common fields for common processing. Anyway, don't let it overgrow, or otherwise later development/debugging will potentially contain lots of confusion.